# Inverse of covariance matrix

Tags: probability, matrices

How to prove that if there exists a vector $\underline a\ne 0$ such that $Var(\sum_i a_iX_i)=0$ the covariance matrix is not invertible?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1479483/321264.

Comment: What if $\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{0}$?

Comment: My bad i should've mentioned that $a$ is a not trivial vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $Var(\sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_i)=0$ can also be written in another form: $$Var\{a^TX\}=0$$which is equivalent to $${E\{(a^TX)^2\}-E^2\{a^TX\}=0
\\E\{a^TXX^Ta\}-E^2\{a^TX\}=0
\\a^TE\{XX^T\}a-E\{a^TX\}E\{X^Ta\}=0
\\a^TE\{XX^T\}a-a^TE\{X\}E\{X^T\}a=0
\\a^T[E\{XX^T\}-E\{X\}E\{X^T\}]a=0
\\a^T\Sigma_X a=0
}$$which means that the covariance matrix $\Sigma_X$ has a $0$ eigenvalue with the corresponding eigenvector $a$ and hence, **is not invertible**.

Comment: Could you explain why $a^T \Sigma _X a=0$ gives us the eigenvalue?
I didnt recall finding eigenvalues by simply multiplying any vecor by matrix and then by its tranpose. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is because since $\Sigma_X$ is symmetric, you can write $\Sigma_X=AA^T$ for some matrix $A$, which leads to $A^Ta=0$ or $AA^Ta=0$.

Comment: I think i'm starting to get it, but i'm still confused a bit
$a^T\Sigma_X a=0
\\a^TAA^T a=0
\\(a^TA)(a^TA)^T=0
$

So i get that $a^TA=0$ but what now? It means $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ but does it imples being eigenvalue of $\Sigma_X$ as well?

Comment: Then it is implied that $A^Ta=0$ and consequently $AA^Ta=0$.