# Is the expectation of an invertible matrix invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$ be an $k$-dimensional random variable, such that $XX' \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$ is invertible.

Does it always follow that $\mathbb{E}[XX']$ is invertible?

---

Let's assume that $\mathbb{E}[X^2_i] < \infty$ for each $i=1,\dots,k$.

I am then thinking of $\mathbb{E}[XX']$ as a $k \times k$ matrix filled with entries like
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{E}[X_1^2] & \mathbb{E}[X_1 X_2] &\dots &\mathbb{E}[X_1X_k] \\
\mathbb{E}[X_2 X_1] &&& \\
\vdots &&&\\
\mathbb{E}[X_kX_1] & \dots & & \mathbb{E}[X^2_k]
\end{pmatrix}
$$
However it's not clear to me that this matrix is always invertible, especially if we don't know the marginal and joint distributions so that the values inside can be anything.

This comes up in statistics in the context of linear regression, where some authors assume $XX'$ is invertible but then later on simply write $\mathbb{E}[XX']^{-1}$ where its implied that it exists.

Comment: If $X X^T$ is invertible then $k$ must be $1$.

Comment: @copper.hat That does strangely seem to be the case. I think I may have misunderstood the shape of $X$. What if $X$ is an $k \times n$ matrix, and $XX'$ is invertible?

Comment: @Adam then it has to be $k\leq n$

Comment: Right, we should have $n >> k$ typically. In this context, $n$ is the sample size and $k$ is the number of variables. An example here is that an author writes (paraphrased) "Assuming $XX'$ is full rank (invertible) almost surely..." and then later on discusses some things involving $\mathbb{E}[XX']^{-1}$. I am not sure why $XX'$ invertible implies $\mathbb{E}[XX']$ is invertible.

Comment: what is $X'$? Is it the transpose of $X$?

Comment: Yeah, $X' = X^T$

Comment: Let $X$ be a 1 times 1 matrix which takes the values $\pm 1$ with equal probability.

Comment: A $X X^T$ matrix is rank 1.

Comment: @Adam It sounds like you're not really sure what you're trying to ask here. Whatever your question is, perhaps [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1479483/81360) answers it.

Comment: note that $X$ *is a function* so $X\not\in \mathbb R^k$.  It seems ok to say $\text{image}(X) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{k}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, here is an educated guess at what the situation is. In a text that you're trying to understand, the author considers a (mean-zero?) random variable $X \in \Bbb R^k$ and a $k \times n$ matrix that I will call $\mathbf X$, whose columns consist of $n$ observed values of $X$. Importantly, we have $n \geq k$. The question is: if it is known that $\mathbf{XX}'$ is invertible (which is only possible for $n \geq k$) almost surely, why can we conclude that $\Bbb E[XX']$ is invertible?

Here's an answer: the matrix $\mathbf C:=\frac 1{n-1} \mathbf{XX}'$ is the *sample covariance*, which is an [unbiased estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimator) of the true covariance. That is, we have
$$
\mathbb E[\mathbf C] = \mathbb E\left[\frac 1{n-1}\mathbf{XX}'\right] = \mathbb E[XX'].
$$
We are given that $\mathbf{XX}'$ is invertible almost surely, hence $\mathbf C = \frac 1{n-1} \mathbf{XX}'$ is invertible almost surely. It suffices to use this to show that $\mathbb E[\mathbf C]$ is invertible.

Towards that end, it helps to note that $\mathbf C$, like the covariance $\mathbb E[\mathbf C]$, is positive semidefinite. Thus, $\mathbf C$ fails to be invertible if and only if there exists a non-zero vector $v$ for which $v' \mathbf C v = 0$, and in either case we always have  $v' \mathbf C v \geq 0$.

Let $v$ be any non-zero vector. Because $\mathbf C$ is invertible with probability $1$, $v' \mathbf C v$ is positive with probability $1$, which implies that $\mathbb E[v'\mathbf C v] > 0$. However, we have
$$
0 < \mathbb E[v'\mathbf C v] = v' \mathbb E[\mathbf C] v.
$$
Because this holds for every non-zero vector $v$, we can conclude that the positive semidefinite matrix $\mathbf E[\mathbb C]$ is invertible.

Comment: Fantastic answer - thank you! In fact, I had not recognized that $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{XX'}]$ is actually the covariance matrix if $X$ is mean $0$. The text I was looking at unfortunately uses the same $X$ to refer to random variables and the matrix of realizations of those random variables.

Comment: On a related note, some authors assume that $\mathbb{E}[XX']$ is invertible. It follows that since (the matrix of observations) $\frac{1}{n-1}\mathbf{XX'}$ converges almost surely to $\mathbb{E}[XX']$ by Strong Law of Large Numbers, then $\mathbf{XX'}$ is invertible almost surely as $n \to \infty$.